# Using Char in an if statement C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, char

Folks, I'm trying to use an 'if' statement with a char variable, but it doesn't seem to notice when the 'yes' condition is met.  I don't know if there's a way to do this without the array.  Here's my code below.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
// Running times calculator

# include <iostream>
# include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    float cTime;
    float gTime;
    float cDist;
    float gDist;

    float min;
    float sec;

    float cMin;
    float cSec;
    float p1000;

    char response[1];

    int blank;

    printf ("Welcome to the running times calculator.\n\nEnter your completed race distance in metres: \n");
    scanf ("%f", &cDist);
    printf("Enter your completed race time. Type minutes, hit enter. Type seconds, hit enter\n");
    scanf ("%f" "%f", &cMin, &cSec);

    cTime = cSec+(60*cMin);
    p1000 = pow(1000/cDist,1.1)*cTime;

    printf ("Would you like to enter another race time to improve prediction accuracy? \n");
    scanf ("%s", &response);

    if(response == "yes")
    {
       printf ("Enter your completed race distance in metres: \n");
       scanf ("%f", &cDist);          
       printf("Enter your completed race time. Type minutes, hit enter. Type seconds, hit enter\n");
       scanf ("%f" "%f", &cMin, &cSec);

       cTime = cSec+(60*cMin);
      p1000 = ((pow(1000/cDist,1.1)*cTime)+p1000)/2;

    }

    printf ("What is your goal race distance in metres? \n");
    scanf ("%f", &gDist);

    gTime = pow(gDist/1000, 1.1)*p1000;
    min = gTime/60;
    sec = remainder(gTime,60);

    if (sec < 0)
    {
    sec = sec + 60;
    min = min - 1;    
    }
    printf ("Your predicted time for a race of %.0f metres is %.0f minutes and %.0f seconds", gDist, min, sec);
    scanf("%f", &blank);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unknown identifier `printf`.  You forgot to `#include <stdio.h>` (or `<cstdio>`)

Comment: @Borgleader: Why is this not C++?  Are there any statements that are not in the C++ language?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews printf, scanf, char arrays. This is C code and thus should be tagged as C.

Comment: @Borgleader: I can compile it under C++.  Does the C++ tag mean that the question must use some C++ language element that is not in the C language?

Comment: wonder why he got `iostream` included...

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It means it should use syntax idiomatic to C++.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: If your code / project is aimed to be C++ code, use the [c++] tag. If it's aimed to be C code, use the [c] tag. Don't use a tag just because it happens to compile in that language.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Uh.. yes. Nothing in here is "strictly C++". Replace #include <iostream>, with #include <stdio.h> and remove the using namespace directive and [this compiles as C code](http://ideone.com/dcRiah)

Comment: Thanks for the input guys.  This is my first code for a C++ compiler. I learned a bit of C a few years ago so I guess I was just using it by habit here

Answer (score 3):

You got a few problems with the way you treat your char array.

`char response[1];` You create an char array that consists of one character here but then you treat it as a string in these lines:

`scanf ("%s", &response);`
`if(response == "yes")`

also note that you can't simply compare a char array and a string literal with `==` all you'd do would be comparing addresses. You'd either have to use strcmp() or better use std::string.

Comment: Also, `scanf ("%s", &response)` invokes UB if `response` is a char array.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Tribse.  I'll start learning how strings work now.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't check all the code, but you use an

```
operator ==
```

that doesn't work with a char [], it's for string
use strcmp instead.